Deobfuscating Pyarmor Files
I have a python pyarmor obfuscated which i want to deobfuscate.
The pyarmor obfuscated file contains the below
Can i get a means of getting back the source code wrapped in the pyarmor?
from pyarmor_runtime_000000 import __pyarmor__
__pyarmor__(__name__, __file__, b'PY000000 /* .... etc ....)

I have tried using unpyarmor. I did not get a breakthrough.

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

If it were trivial to do so, then pyarmor would not be much of a protection. What you’re asking for will be nontrivial unless someone has already written such a tool for the specific version used to obfuscate the code, or you have good experience with reverse engineering. Note too that you aren’t going to get original source code back in any case: the best you can hope for is compiled Python bytecode, which might be decompiled to readable source (or not).

Please check the version of your pyarmor encryption. If it is v7 version. You can see this project https://github.com/Svenskithesource/PyArmor-Unpacker. If it's v8, then you need to know a little bit about pyarmor principles and python source code knowledge to restore the bytecode (provided the encryption used is not in bbc mode, etc.)
